# Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Сам запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, 
  p.autor, 
  p.date, 
  p.short_story, 
  CHAR_LENGTH(p.full_story) as full_story, 
  p.xfields, 
  e.rating,
  e.votes,
  e.reason 
FROM dle_post p 
LEFT JOIN dle_post_extras e ON (p.id=e.news_id) 
WHERE p.date >= 2017-06-12 06:04:15 - INTERVAL 120 DAY 
  AND p.date < 2017-06-12 06:04:15 
  AND approve=1 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

Ошибка:

```
syntax error at or near "06" СТРОКА 1: ... e ON (p.id=e.news_id) WHERE p.date >= 2017-06-12 06:04:15 -... ^
```

Впервые работаю с базой postgres и не могу понять в чем именно ошибка. Что с кавычками ' что без, одна и та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение, добавив `::timestamp` к датам:

```
WHERE p.date >= '2017-06-12 07:04:37'::timestamp - INTERVAL '120 DAY' AND p.date < '2017-06-12 07:04:37'::timestamp
```

вдруг кому-то пригодится.

Comment: Так напишите в чём конкретно была ваша ошибка и как именно вы её исправили.

Comment: @Chloroform написа